# Two elements in the set differ by 3 or more

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

> Call a set of integers *sparse* if any two elements in the set differ by at least 3. Find the number of sparse subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, 12\}.$ (Both $\emptyset$ and one-element sets are *sparse*, to my understanding.) For example, {$1, 5, 11, 12$} is a *sparse* set, since $1$ and $5$ differ by 3 or more.

I was thinking of a way using recursion. Here's my approach:

Call $a_n$ the number of sparse sets in the set of integers {$1, 2, 3, \dots, n$}.  If we look at the set {$1, 2, 3, \dots, n-1$}, there are $a_{n-1}$ sparse sets. If we assign $n-1$ to a sparse set, when we incorporate $n$, then we can either

- include $n$ in the sparse set
- include $n$ and remove $n-1$ in the sparse set
- keep it as it is.

There are $3$ cases, each with the same value, so we have $a_n = 3a_{n-1}$ so far.

However, I don't know how to continue, and I'm not even sure if my current approach is correct.

Comment: Wouldn't we also have to remove $n - 2$ in order to include $n$?

Comment: Either $n$ is in the set, in which case you have $a_{n-3}$ since we know that $ n-2, n-1$ can't be in the set, or $n$ is not in the set, in which case you have $a_{n-1}$.

Comment: @lulu I thought that at first, but it's just if *any two elements* differ by at least $3$. So for example, the set $1, 5, 10, 11$ is valid too.

Comment: @FruDe $10$ and $11$ do not differ by at least $3$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, but $1$ and $5$ do. Again it's just if **any** two elements differ. Not all have to differ by at least 3.

Comment: @FruDe  I read the condition as requiring that no two elements are closer than $3$, so I would not count the set you propose.

Comment: I agree with @lulu.

Comment: @lulu Alright, I'll go with that. So then the recursion would be $a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}$.

Comment: That's my conclusion.

Comment: Good! I'll let you know if it's incorrect and that if it's *any* two integers are 3 or more apart, but I think we got the interpretation of the problem. @lulu

Comment: @lulu, it's incorrect. It seems a set like $1, 5, 10, 11$ is also *sparse* since 1 and 5 differ by 3 or more.

Comment: That is very hard to believe.  You'd say the set $\{1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ is a $\textit {sparse}$ subset of the first $10$ natural numbers?  It's almost all of them!

Comment: But, if you really mean the condition you propose then it is easier to count the sets which violate it.  Count the subsets such that every element is within three of another element.

Comment: I also suggest editing your post for clarity...I think that nearly everyone will read the condition the way I did.

Comment: "any two elements in the set differ by at least 3" is ambiguous.  Allowing (for example $\{1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, while allowable (perhaps) to an English teacher, would render the problem all but trivial.  It does seem reasonable to (alternatively) interpret the problem as lulu and N. F. Taussig have done.

Comment: Thanks @lulu, I edited the question to try to make it more clear.

Comment: When mathematicians say something like "any two" they mean "for *all* pairs." Your interpretation seems closer to saying "for *some* pair."

Comment: The word *sparse* means "of few and scattered elements" (Merriam Webster) or "thinly scattered or distributed" (dictionary.com).  Your interpretation cannot be reconciled with these definitions.

Comment: @FruDe so what was the correct solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n$ be the set of sparse subsets on $\{1..n\}$. Then $S_0 = \{\emptyset\}$, $S_1 = \{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$, $S_2 = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}\}$, and in general

$S_{n + 3} = S_{n + 2} \cup \{A \cup \{n + 3\} : A \in S_n\}$

Define $F_n = |S_n|$. Then we see that $F_0 = 1$, $F_1 = 2$, $F_2 = 3$, and $F_{n + 3} = F_{n + 2} + F_n$.

To efficiently calculate $F_n$, we note that, defining

$M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

We have

$M \begin{pmatrix} F_{n + 2} \\ F_{n + 1} \\ F_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} F_{n + 3} \\ F_{n + 2} \\ F_{n + 1} \end{pmatrix}$

And consequently, by induction on $n$, we have

$M^n \begin{pmatrix} F_{2} \\ F_{1} \\ F_0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} F_{n + 2} \\ F_{n + 1} \\ F_{n} \end{pmatrix}$

Calculating $M^n$ will take $O(\log n)$ multiplications.